# Inference of Model on Sagemaker Failing

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, inference

I have uploaded a tensorflow model model.tar.gz to Sagemaker and then i do the following code to inference

```
import boto3
import json

client = boto3.client('sagemaker-runtime')

response = client.invoke_endpoint(
    EndpointName="tensorflow-inference-2024-01-14-14-11-34-629",
    ContentType="application/json",
    Body=mock_request_json  # JSON string payload
)

print(response['Body'].read().decode())
```

I get the error:

````
ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from primary with message "{
    "error": "Failed to process element: 0 key: data of 'instances' list. Error: Invalid argument: JSON object: does not have named input: data"
}". See https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-1#logEventViewer:group=/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/tensorflow-inference-2024-01-14-14-11-34-629 in account 969632233674 for more information.```

However, I have an old deployed endpoint that works fine with the same code but it works fine. I checked all the code and it seems the same except for some minor difference in the folder structure of model.tar.gz. Any ideas what could be causing teh error ?

Also as referece, here is my deployment code:

```import sagemaker
from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlowModel
from sagemaker.deserializers import JSONDeserializer
from utilities.sagemaker_utils.training_utils import delete_endpoint, get_last_training_job, deploy_trained_model
import json

model_name = "search-ranking-model"
training_job = "search-ranking-model-2023-12-24-09-01-19-826"  # replace with the actual training job

try:
    predictor = deploy_trained_model(
        model_name=model_name,
        training_job=training_job,
        instance_type='ml.m5.large',
        framework='tensorflow',
        framework_version='2.6',  # replace with the version used during training
        py_version='py38'  # replace with the python version used during training
    )
    predictor.deserializer = JSONDeserializer()
except Exception as e:
    # Log the exception and handle any cleanup if necessary
    print(f"An error occurred during model deployment: {e}")
````

[image: Folder Structure of model.tar.gz]